# Integrating a Linux Machine Into Windows Active Directory Domain

Tags: active-directory, redhat, connect

I am working in a enterprise company and had to make a project to connect some linux servers (Red Hat versions 6-8) to ActiveDirectory.

After some tests I got to a point where I can connect correctly with AD credentials to the servers. My testing servers where brand new and I haven't connected a production machine.

Now I am wondering what may happen to the local users (and their credentials) when I connect those machines to my AD, because my users are using the same user name as in AD.

Has anyone done this before and can suggest some tests beforehand?

Comment: What is the end goal? Creating a machine account for the box so that it can communicate with the AD is one thing, being able to login as AD user on the machine is different (but might already have happened, but that is up to configuration of the distribution)

Comment: shortly, nothing they stay valid until revoked